# String Exist Check and Echo to File

Tags: batch, script, batch-file

guys. I was so immensely helped the last time I came here that I thought I'd come back for more, lol. Seriously, though. Those who helped in my last question have saved me hours of work in the last few days alone. A thanks to them again!

What I need to do this time is the following:
For each folder in this directory: "F:\!Storage\!FS Addons\!X-Plane\!Tools\!Ortho4XP\Tiles"

Do the following:

1) Check if a folder name exists in a file in a different directory:
 "E:\X Plane 11\X-Plane 11\Custom Scenery\scenery_packs.ini"
2) If NOT exist, echo folder name into file (scenery_packs.ini)
3) If exist, do not echo (basically just ignore) and continue to check next folder until finished

I know that to to echo something into a file you use `echo Hello, World! >> file.ini`

My problem is with the variables since there are multiple folders. I'm very bad with my `FOR` loops :(

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I tried coming up with this but it's as best as I could do with my knowledge and experience. Check it out:

`@echo off
setlocal

set "target=F:\!Storage\!FS Addons\!X-Plane\!Tools\!Ortho4XP\Tiles"
set "destination=E:\X Plane 11\X-Plane 11\Custom Scenery\scenery_packs.ini"

 for %%a in ("%target%") do (
  findstr %%~nxA 
  if exist IGNORE 
  )else(
  echo %%~nxA >> %destination% )

endlocal
pause`

Comment: Also I just realized I'm in superuser... ugh! Sorry! Will head over to SO

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test on a real system, but should be ok:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set BaseFolder=F:\!Storage\!FS Addons\!X-Plane\!Tools\!Ortho4XP\Tiles
set FileForSearch=E:\X Plane 11\X-Plane 11\Custom Scenery\scenery_packs.ini
set NewFoldersList=%~dp0\NewFolders.txt

if exist ("!NewFoldersList!") (
  del /q "!NewFoldersList!" >nul 2>&1
)

for /d /r %%A in ("!BaseFolder!") do (
  set tmp_FolderFound=N

  for /f %%B in ("!FileForSearch!") do (
    if /i not [!FolderFound!]==[S] (
      if /i [%%A]==[%%B] (
        set tmp_FolderFound=S
        echo %%A>>"!NewFoldersList!"
      )
    )
  )
)

if exist ("!NewFoldersList!") (
  copy /b "!FileForSearch!"+"!NewFoldersList!" "!FileForSearch!" >nul 2>&1
)

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
endlocal
```